# How to batch Stored Procedure with sequential on Azure Data Factory Pipeline?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, foreach, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have Stored Procedure pipeline on Azure Data Factory, my Stored Procedure need to run with parameter using `DateTime`, but I have a problem here, I need to Batch my Stored Procedure with differen parameter.

For Example

Stored Procedure 1 , `DateTime` value `2020-05-01`

Stored Procedure 2 , `DateTime` value `2020-06-01`

Stored Procedure 3 , `DateTime` value `2020-07-01`

...

Can I using `ForEach` method on this ? So, this `ForEach` will stored every step of Stored Procedure, and run it sequence on the pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your ask, you need to create a parameter or variable of type array with all the values in sequence.
Use that as an input for the foreach activity and enable sequential execution of for each activity and within for each activity have a stored procedure activity with the input parameter as the for each activity execution loop value

Comment: So, I will use Stored Procedure to exece the script, and Add some `Variable` for the input, and how about the sequential execution ? What thing that I need to do this sequence ?

Comment: Hey, for sequential execution there is a property within the for each activity specifying whether the loop flow should be parallel or sequential

Comment: I see, okay I will try it first then, btw thank you for the answer !